# nameError: global name page_title undefined

Tags: python, nameerror

I looked at many of the exisiting nameErrors and undefined variable posts and unfortunately was unable to resolve my issue. I am relatively new to programming and especially Python.

I have a dictionary of dictionaries defined in informcast_data.py:

```
allLinks = {'Send or Edit Messages': {'link':'/InformaCast/admin?cmd=listMessages',   'page_title': 'Messages: Send or Edit Messages'}
```

I am importing informacast_data.py to users.py:

```
from informacast.informacast_data import ICData
```

I then have a function, verify_links which has the following for statement:

```
for href_link in hrefs:
    if href_link.find(ICData.allLinks['page_title']['link'])!=-1:
        self.logger.debug("verify_links found=True for " + str(href_link))
        found=True
```

If I leave quotes around page_title I get a keyError and I was told to remove the quotes as it is a variable not a string, I get the nameError when I remove the quotes and I am not sure how to proceed.

below is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jesse.sole\Jesse_Workspace\trunk\src\informacast\tests\users.py", line 17, in test_appadmin_role
    self.verify_role("appAdmin")
  File "C:\Users\jesse.sole\Jesse_Workspace\trunk\src\informacast\tests\users.py", line 78, in verify_role
    self.verify_links(sel, roleName)
  File "C:\Users\jesse.sole\Jesse_Workspace\trunk\src\informacast\tests\users.py", line 104, in verify_links
    if href_link.find(ICData.allLinks[page_title]['link'])!=-1:
NameError: global name 'page_title' is not defined
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: There is no NameError in this code. Please show us the full traceback of the error.

Comment: full traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jesse.sole\Jesse_Workspace\trunk\src\informacast\tests\users.py", line 17, in test_appadmin_role
    self.verify_role("appAdmin")
  File "C:\Users\jesse.sole\Jesse_Workspace\trunk\src\informacast\tests\users.py", line 78, in verify_role
    self.verify_links(sel, roleName)
  File "C:\Users\jesse.sole\Jesse_Workspace\trunk\src\informacast\tests\users.py", line 104, in verify_links
    if href_link.find(ICData.allLinks[page_title]['link'])!=-1:
NameError: global name 'page_title' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allLinks` is a nested dictionary. The top level has no `page_title` key, so that's why you get a key error:

```
>>> allLinks = {'Send or Edit Messages': {'link':'/InformaCast/admin?cmd=listMessages',   'page_title': 'Messages: Send or Edit Messages'}}
>>> allLinks['page_title']                                                                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'page_title'
```

There *is* such a key in the nested dictionary though:

```
>>> allLinks['Send or Edit Messages']['page_title']
'Messages: Send or Edit Messages'
```

I *think* you want to define a variable `page_title` that has the value `'Send or Edit Messages'`:

```
>>> page_title = 'Send or Edit Messages'
>>> allLinks[page_title]['link']
'/InformaCast/admin?cmd=listMessages'
```

If you loop over the keys in `allLinks` that would work:

```
for href_link in hrefs:
    for page_title in ICData.allLinks:
        if href_link.find(ICData.allLinks[page_title]['link'])!=-1:
            self.logger.debug("verify_links found=True for " + str(href_link))
            found=True
```

Comment: The keyError makes sense and I understand now. Send or edit messages is one of over 50 nested dict in allLinks. I need the for loop to look at all links and find the page_title to verify functionality. I see now that 'page_title' in informacast_data.py is undefined when I remove the quotes. It is not clear to me where and how to define it.